# Как в Google Play Console скрыть свой адрес?

Tags: android, google-play

Как в Google Play Console скрыть свой адрес? Типа сделать его конфиденциальным...

Или выборочно открытым для разных стран?

Вот пример скрытого адреса:

**Разработчик**

**Написать: xxx@gmail.com**

**Конфиденциальность**

[Ссылка на этого разработчика в Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vacaeducation.englishtensesinenglish)

Как он это сделал? )

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Разработчик обязан указать свой адрес, сделав его видным всем пользователям. Вы можете лишь сократить его. Например оставить только город/улицу. Скорее всего гугл такое пропустит и ваш точный адрес будет защищён.

Comment: Пожалуйста, посмотрите пример скрытого адреса, который я добавил в вопрос!!!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, тут есть нюансы)) 
Если ваше приложение НЕ платное или в приложениях НЕТ внутренних покупок, то конкретный адрес указывать не надо. И никто вас за это не накажет. Вы просто будете получать отчисления от Гугла за показ рекламы (если вы настроили) в вашем приложении. Но, если ваше приложение платное или пользователь что-то в приложении покупает за реальные деньги, то, в соответствии с законом о защите прав потребителей, вы обязаны указать свой фактический адрес. И Гугл за этим следит. В этом вся фишка с адресами. Это написано под полем заполнения адресного блока в консоли:

> Укажите свой текущий почтовый адрес, чтобы пользователи могли связаться с вами. Если вы продаете приложения или контент через них, то, согласно нашим условиям и законам о защите прав потребителей, вы должны предоставить актуальные данные. В противном случае мы можем заблокировать ваш аккаунт и/или снять с продажи ваши приложения. Указывая свой почтовый адрес или адрес электронной почты, вы разрешаете Google публиковать их на страницах, связанных с вашими приложениями.